# Pandas dataframe to json list format

Tags: json, pandas

I have large pandas tabular dataframe to convert into JSON.
The standard .to_json() functions does not make a compact format for JSON.
How to get JSON output forma like this,  using pandas only ?

```
{"index": [ 0, 1 ,3 ],
 "col1": [ "250", "1" ,"3" ],
 "col2": [ "250", "1" ,"3" ]
}
```

This is a much compact format form of JSON for tabular data.
(I can do a loop over the rows.... but)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you need [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) first and then `dict` to `json`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [ 0, 1 ,3 ],
 "col1": [ "250", "1" ,"3" ],
 "col2": [ "250", "1" ,"3" ]
})
print (df)
  col1 col2  index
0  250  250      0
1    1    1      1
2    3    3      3


print (df.to_dict(orient='list'))
{'col1': ['250', '1', '3'], 'col2': ['250', '1', '3'], 'index': [0, 1, 3]}
```

---

```
import json

print (json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='list')))
{"col1": ["250", "1", "3"], "col2": ["250", "1", "3"], "index": [0, 1, 3]}
```

Because it is not [implemented yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7863#issuecomment-51053948):

```
print (df.to_json(orient='list'))
```

> ValueError: Invalid value 'list' for option 'orient'

EDIT:

If index is not column, add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [250, 1, 3],
                   "col2": [250, 1, 3]})
print (df)
   col1  col2
0   250   250
1     1     1
2     3     3

print (df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='list'))
{'col1': [250, 1, 3], 'index': [0, 1, 2], 'col2': [250, 1, 3]}
```

Comment: You are always faster ;-)

Comment: If you may have NaN values in your data, `to_dict` + `json.dump` will not be able to manage them as `null` as `to_json` can do. You will get `NaN` word in your result which may be invalid JSON file.

Comment: @PascalH. - then convert `NaN` to `None`, so `json.dump` create `null` - `print (json.dumps(df.mask(df.isna(), None).to_dict(orient='list')))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_dict` and `json` (and add the `index` as extra column if required via `assign`):

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [250, 1, 3],
                   "col2": [250, 1, 3]})

json_dict = df.assign(index=df.index).to_dict(orient="list")
print(json.dumps(json_dict))

>>> '{"index": [0, 1, 2], "col1": [250, 1, 3], "col2": [250, 1, 3]}'
```