# Convert numpy array of Datetime objects to UTC strings

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a large array of datetime objects in numpy array. However I am trying to export them as a json object attribute and need them to be represented as a UTC string.

Here is my array ( a small chunk of it )

```
datetimes = [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 14, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 32, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 50, tzinfo=<UTC>)]

json = {
    'datetimes': []
};
```

I know I can iterate over the list and convert them however I was hoping there was an efficient pandas or numpy technique for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create `DataFrame`, convert to `iso` format and save to `dict`, because [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with `orint='list'` is [not implemented yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43134775/2901002):

```
datetimes = [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 50, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)] 


df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimes': datetimes})
#native convert to iso, but not support lists yet
print (df.to_json(date_format='iso'))
{"datetimes":{"0":"2015-07-12T18:33:14.000Z",
              "1":"2015-07-12T18:33:32.000Z",
              "2":"2015-07-12T18:33:50.000Z"}}

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimes': datetimes})
df['datetimes'] = df['datetimes'].map(lambda x: x.isoformat())
print (json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='l')))
{"datetimes": ["2015-07-12T18:33:14+00:00", 
               "2015-07-12T18:33:32+00:00", 
               "2015-07-12T18:33:50+00:00"]}

print(json.dumps({'datetimes': [x.isoformat() for x in datetimes]}))
{"datetimes": ["2015-07-12T18:33:14+00:00", 
               "2015-07-12T18:33:32+00:00", 
               "2015-07-12T18:33:50+00:00"]}
```

I test it more and list comprehension is fastest with `isoformat`:

```
datetimes = [datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
             datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 12, 18, 33, 50, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]*10000

In [116]: %%timeit 
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimes': datetimes})
     ...: df['datetimes'] = df['datetimes'].map(lambda x: x.isoformat())
     ...: json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='l'))
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 552 ms per loop

#wrong output format, dictionaries not lists
In [117]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'datetimes': datetimes})
     ...: df.to_json(date_format='iso')
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop

In [118]: %%timeit
     ...: json.dumps({'datetimes': [x.isoformat() for x in datetimes]})
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 67.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: This looks fantastic. I will verify and mark correct as soon as possible. Thank you so very much. I really appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Ya, not easy timezone problematic ;) Thank you.